# Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'student' available as request attribute - Spring MVC

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

First I'd like to say that I have read many questions and answers about this error here on SO (and other places), but non helped for this specific case.

Scenario for my simple Spring MVC web app is this: user searches for a student (searchStudent.jsp) based on the String property indexNumber. indexNumber consists of 3 other properties which are entered by the user: programId, rollNumber, rollYear. For example, if programId="M5", rollNumber="10" and rollYear="2013", indexNumber will be "M5 10/13". This is done in the view. indexNumber is a unique identifier for every student, but is not PK. Important note: searching for student and loading the appropriate page works fine on it's own.

If student doesn't exist, addAfterSearchStudent.jsp page is suppose to load with pre-populated values user entered in the searchStudent.jsp (programId, rollNumber, indexNumber) - I don't want to make user enter this data twice. I wrote the code bellow that I thought will do exactly what I described here, but I get the mentioned error. This also works fine when I hard-code these properties and try to save data. I believe problem is in passing params from one jsp to other.

These are handler methods from my controller:

```
    /**
     * Handles and retrieves the search student page
     */
    @RequestMapping(value="/search", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getSearchStudent(Model model) {

        logger.debug("Received request to show search student page");

        model.addAttribute("index", new Student());
        model.addAttribute("programList", programService.getAll());

        return "searchStudent";
    }

    /**
     * Searches for a student by delegating the processing to StudentService.
     */
    @RequestMapping(value="/search", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String postSearchStudent(@RequestParam(value = "program.programId") String programId,
                                    @RequestParam(value = "rollNumber") String rollNumber,
                                    @RequestParam(value = "rollYear") String rollYear,
                                    @RequestParam(value = "indexNumber") String indexNumber,
                                    Model model) {

        logger.debug("Received request to search for a student");

        model.addAttribute("program.programId", programId);
        model.addAttribute("rollNumber", rollNumber);
        model.addAttribute("rollYear", rollYear);
        model.addAttribute("indexNumber", indexNumber);

        // Call StudentService to do the actual searching
        Student student = studentService.search(indexNumber);

        // if student isn't in the db load addAfterSearchStudent.jsp, else load student.jsp
        if (student == null)
            return "addAfterSearchStudent";
        else
            return "student";
    }

    /**
     * Handles and retrieves the add (after search) student page
     */
    @RequestMapping(value="/addSearch", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getAddSearchStudent(@RequestParam(value = "program.programId") String programId,
                                    @RequestParam(value = "rollNumber") String rollNumber,
                                    @RequestParam(value = "rollYear") String rollYear,
                                    @RequestParam(value = "indexNumber") String indexNumber,
                                    Model model) {

        logger.debug("Received request to show add (after search) student page");

        Student student = new Student();
        student.setRollNumber(rollNumber);
        student.setRollYear(rollYear);
        student.setIndexNumber(indexNumber);
        Program program = programService.get(programId);
        student.setProgram(program);
        model.addAttribute("student", student);

        return "addAfterSearchStudent";
    }

    /**
     * Adds a new student after search by delegating the processing to StudentService.
     * Displays a confirmation JSP page
     */
    @RequestMapping(value="/addSearch", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String postAddSearchStudent(@ModelAttribute("student") Student student) {

        logger.debug("Received request to add new student after search");

        // Call StudentService to do the actual adding
        studentService.addAfterSearch(student);

        // resolves to /WEB-INF/jsp/success/addStudentSuccess.jsp
        return "/success/addStudentSuccess";
    }
```

This is searchStudent.jsp:

```
<c:url var="searchUrl" value="/essays/main/student/search" />
<form:form modelAttribute="index" method="POST" action="${searchUrl}">
...
```

This is addAfterSearchStudent.jsp:

```
<c:url var="saveUrl" value="/essays/main/student/addSearch" />
<form:form commandName="student" method="POST" action="${saveUrl}">
...
```

I know this is long, but I wanted to present all relevant information.
Does anyone have an idea where I'm making a mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form:form commandName="student" ...>
```

Your `addAfterSearchStudent.jsp` expects an object named 'student'. In your `postSearchStudent()` method you don't add one to the model.

```
if (student == null)
  return "addAfterSearchStudent";
```

You need to create a `Student` object and add it, like you do it in the `getAddSearchStudent()` method.

```
    Student student = new Student();
    student.setRollNumber(rollNumber);
    student.setRollYear(rollYear);
    student.setIndexNumber(indexNumber);
    Program program = programService.get(programId);
    student.setProgram(program);
    model.addAttribute("student", student);
```

Comment: '@zeroflagL' thanks, this works. I also discovered that the code I posted above works if I put `return "redirect:/essays/main/student/addSearch"` instead of `return "addAfterSearchStudent"`. I read about redirect in spring docs but didn't really understand. Can you pls explain the difference between those two, or point me to some other source?

Comment: @just_a_girl the redirect tells the browser to call the URL "/essays/main/student/addSearch" which in turn means that the method `getAddSearchStudent()` is called. It's almost like you enter this URL yourself directly in your browser.